# Why always "skirt-flipping" fan-service's (mini-skirt blowing up.)?

Tags: tropes

Sometimes in anime/manga, I see some scene's where the MC flip the skirt of the heroine, or even some random character with a cute face. I know there are many kind of fan-service's like groping breast, yuri scene's, etc. But why is it almost always skirt flipping ? Like it is the standard of fan-service.

Is there story behind it? Where does this originate from?

Comment: This isn't limited to anime. For as long as there's been skirts, in some medium, some author or artist has described flipping it.

Comment: I rephrased the question quite a bit. If any context is lost feel free to revert, or edit the information back in.

Answer (score 9):

I have made some research and this is what i got (and sorry about my grammar )

So it called `Panchira (パンチラ)` refers to a brief glimpse of a woman's underwear.

> Panchira (パンチラ) refers to a brief glimpse of a woman's underwear. The
>   term carries risqué connotations similar to the word 'upskirt' in
>   English usage. The word is a portmanteau of "panty" (パンティー pantī) and
>   chira, the Japanese sound symbolism representing a glance or
>   glimpse. It differs from the more general term "upskirt" in that
>   panchira specifies the presence of underpants (the absence of which
>   would more accurately be described as ノーパン; nōpan).

**Origins**

> **Traditionally, Japanese women did not wear underwear.** On December 16,
>   1932, there was a fire in the Tokyo Shirokiya department store. Legend
>   has it that some of the female staff tried to use their kimonos to
>   cover their privates as they climbed down ropes from the higher
>   floors, and accidentally fell to their deaths. Japanese newspapers
>   began agitating for women to start wearing 'drawers' (ズローズ zurōzu),
>   but seemingly had little impact at the time. In a 1934 survey by a
>   Fukuoka newspaper, 90% of the women surveyed were still not wearing
>   'drawers' a year and a half after the fire.[2](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=WkJ9AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT446&lpg=PT446&dq=skirt%20flipping%20culture%20in%20japan&source=bl&ots=LhGN8iCxnu&sig=O9j3-t-mDOaf34vLQxM_4gRj4cE&hl=id&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip8PHEyoHWAhWIL48KHdqPDc0Q6AEIWzAL#v=onepage&q=skirt%20flipping%20culture%20in%20japan&f=false)
>
> As noted below, the development of panchira in Japanese popular
>   culture has been analyzed by a number of American and Japanese
>   writers. Many observers link the phenomenon to the Westernization of
>   Japan following World War II.[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchira) During the occupation, fashions,
>   ideas, and media previously unavailable were accessed by the local
>   population, leading to a slight relaxing of earlier taboos.
>   Western-style clothing (including women's underwear) gained popularity
>   in the post-war period, reinforced through numerous media outlets —
>   magazines, newspapers, films, journals, and comics.
>
> At least one Japanese source traces the beginnings of panchira to the
>   release of The Seven Year Itch in 1955.[8] The media coverage
>   surrounding Marilyn Monroe's iconic scene fueled the emerging Japanese
>   craze. According to architectural historian Shoichi Inoue, the
>   practice of "scoring" a glimpse up young women's skirts became
>   extremely popular around this period; "Magazines of the time have
>   articles telling the best places where panties could be viewed".[9]
>   Inoue also writes that actress Mitsuyo Asaka spurred the popularity of
>   the word 'chirarizumu' (チラリズム 'the thrill of catching a brief glimpse
>   of a women's nether regions') by parting her kimono to show off her
>   legs in her stage shows in the late 1950s.[10]
>
> In 1969, the Japanese oil company Maruzen Sekiyū released a television
>   commercial featuring Rosa Ogawa in a short mini-skirt that gets blown
>   up by the wind with her forming her lips into an 'O' in surprise. This
>   led to children imitating her line "Oh! Mōretsu" (Oh！モーレツ, too much,
>   radical), and a fad for sukāto-mekuri (スカート捲り flipping up of a girl's
>   skirt).[11] Ogawa subsequently appeared in a TV show Oh Sore Miyo (Oh!
>   それ見よ, literally "look at that," but actually a pun on 'O Sole Mio,' a
>   neapolitan song 'my sunshine') that again featured scenes of her
>   mini-skirt blowing up.

**Anime/Manga**

For anime/manga culture,  it's 'partially' answered from this question.

[Where did the anime trope of Clothing Damage / Clothes being torn originate?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28469/where-did-the-anime-trope-of-clothing-damage-clothes-being-torn-originate)

it was from this manga, Shameless School

**Wiki Explanation**

> Harenchi Gakuen (ハレンチ学園, lit. "Shameless School") is a Japanese media
>   franchise created by Go Nagai. Harenchi Gakuen was one of the manga
>   serialized in the very first issue of Shueisha's manga magazine Weekly
>   Shōnen Jump. The series was the first big success for Go Nagai. It is
>   also considered as the first modern erotic manga, sometimes considered
>   the first hentai manga, though Nagai never used explicit sexual
>   situations in the original run of the manga.

And from the same wiki, it was written

> By the late 1960s, panchira had
>   spread to the mainstream comic industry, as fledgling manga artists
>   such as Go Nagai began exploring sexual imagery in boys' comics
>   (shōnen manga).[12] Adult manga magazines had existed since 1956 (e.g.
>   Weekly Manga Times), but it is significant to note the introduction of
>   sexual imagery into boys manga. Millegan argues that the ecchi genre
>   of the 1970s rose to fill a void left by the decline of Osaka's
>   lending library network:[13]

and i read an article about Shueisha’s Weekly Shonen Jump came under fire for running a busty spread on Yuragi-sō no Yūna-san (Yūna of Yuragi Manor). The illustration sparked conversations about ecchi works in a magazine that is largely seen as reading material for kids under 14 years of age.

**Summary**

From what i could tell, the originate of "skirt-flipping" is from short mini-skirt that gets blown up by the wind ). There is a book with titles, `Perversion and Modern Japan: Psychoanalysis, Literature, Culture` that explain about this topic, but i couldn't copy the reference's, since its licensed. You could read the book online [Here](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=WkJ9AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT446&lpg=PT446&dq=skirt%20flipping%20culture%20in%20japan&source=bl&ots=LhGN8iCxnu&sig=O9j3-t-mDOaf34vLQxM_4gRj4cE&hl=id&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip8PHEyoHWAhWIL48KHdqPDc0Q6AEIWzAL#v=onepage&q=skirt%20flipping%20culture%20in%20japan&f=false)

---

**References**

- [Perversion and Modern Japan: Psychoanalysis, Literature, Culture](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=WkJ9AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT446&lpg=PT446&dq=skirt%20flipping%20culture%20in%20japan&source=bl&ots=LhGN8iCxnu&sig=O9j3-t-mDOaf34vLQxM_4gRj4cE&hl=id&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip8PHEyoHWAhWIL48KHdqPDc0Q6AEIWzAL#v=onepage&q=skirt%20flipping%20culture%20in%20japan&f=false)
- [Panchira (パンチラ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchira)

Answer (score -3):

This is the rule. This is the one of animation's principles. Follow Through and Overlapping Action. 
The artist is to make animation look like living motion, when character move, the skirt need to follow up and move.
Follow Through and Overlapping Action is one of principles. Originate from Disney. Animator all having this concept.

For fan-service, Anime when skirt-flipping, it increase charm of the character, it also is fan-service. Cute, Cute poses, Smile, kawaii, sexy, charming, eye contact more is all fan-service. Behind the story is  is the fact and originate from Japan.

[The fact, behind of story, fan-service because... (read more)](https://injapan.gaijinpot.com/play/culture/2012/11/09/why-japanese-people-are-comfortable-with-nakedness/)

https://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2016/07/Rapunzel.gif

Comment: Yes. Skirt-Flipping is Fan-service. It increase charm of female character to charm audience or others character in anime/manga series.

Comment: given the other examples of fan service in the question i think you misunderstand what skirt flipping is going by the .gifs you have posted. if i am correct skit flipping in this case is when the flipper lifts the girl's skirt exposing her underwear, ie [this](http://pa1.narvii.com/5800/8a10f30fda2ca4617ba6cbac9c72bc8bcdadb5a1_hq.gif)